# React DataTable insert action link

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-data-table-component

Good afternoon!
I have react-data-table-component

I'm trying to create a column that will have action buttons (delete/edit...)
To do this, in clickHandler I need to pass parameters from data, for example ID or possibly even additional parameters.
At the moment I'm trying to pass one ID parameter and I'm not getting anything

```
function DataBase (){

    const clickHandler = (state) => {
        console.log("ID",state.target.id);
    };

    const data = ([
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Beetlejuice',
            year: '1988',
            action: "d-1",
            cell:(row) => <a href={row.title} onClick={clickHandler} id="d1">Action</a>,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Ghostbusters',
            year: '1984',
            action: "d-2",
            cell:(row) => <a href={row.title} onClick={clickHandler} id="d-2">Action</a>,
        },
    ]);

    const columns = [
        {
            name: 'Title',
            selector: row => row.title,
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'Year',
            selector: row => row.year,
        },
        {
            name: 'Action',
            selector: row => row.action,
            cell: () => <a href="#" onClick={clickHandler}>Action</a>,
            ignoreRowClick: true,
            allowOverflow: true,
            button: true,
        },
    ];

return (
            <PageWrapper>
                <DataTable
                 columns={columns}
                 data={data}
                 pagination
               />
            </PageWrapper>
        );
}

export default DataBase;


}
```

No matter how I tried I can't get the ID in clickHandler

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: You can also pass the **cell** property to the ``columns`` instead of the ``data``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `props` from the cell and pass down the props to click handler like,

```
  cell: (props) => (
    <a
      href="#"
      onClick={() => {
        clickHandler(props);
      }}
    >
      Action
    </a>
  );
```

And in `clickHandler` get it like,

```
  const clickHandler = (state) => {
    console.log("ID ", state.id);
  };
```

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit charming-hamilton-1b2lfq]

Comment: @Sergo, If the answer solved your issue then feel free to accept and close the answer. To accept, you will find a tick below voting arrows in the answer.